# IIR implementation - RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, infinite-impulse-response, software-implementation

I have implemented a butter filter in python using this function:

```
def butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    return b, a
```

b and a:

```
array([1.53324552e-09, 6.13298208e-09, 9.19947312e-09, 6.13298208e-09, 1.53324552e-09])
array([ 1.        , -3.9671626 ,  5.90202586, -3.90255878,  0.96769554])
```

Now I have to do an implementation. When testing different algorithms, I have the following problem:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
```

How to avoid this problem? Perform scaling? The problem, in my opinion, is the b coefficients.
When I call the function `lfilter` everything is OK

The code and data: https://github.com/Rariusz/IIR-implementation.git

The actual IIR implementation:

```
N = order1
L = len(data)
x = np.zeros(L,dtype=np.float64)
u = np.zeros(L,dtype=np.float64)
y = np.zeros(L,dtype=np.float64)
a = a1
b = b1

for n in range(L):

  for i in range(N,1,-1):
    x[n-i-1] = x[n-i]
  x[n] = data[n]

  y[n] = 0
  for i in range(N):
    y[n] = y[n] + b[i]*x[n-i]

  for i in range(1,N):
    y[n] = y[n] + a[i]*y[n-i]
```

[image]

**Solution**:

```
y = np.zeros(len(data))
x = data
for n in range(4,len(data)):
  y[n] = -(a[1]*y[n-1] + a[2]*y[n-2] + a[3]*y[n-3] + a[4]*y[n-4]) + \
         b[0]*x[n] + b[1]*x[n-1] + b[2]*x[n-2] + b[3]*x[n-3] + b[4]*x[n-4]
```

Comment: well how are we supposed to help you debug implementations that you don't show us!

Comment: Your coefficients are fine. The poles are fairly close to the unit circle but not close enough that you should get numerical issues with double precision even if it's a "bad" implementation like Transposed Form I or Direct Form II

Comment: @MarcusMüller  I updated the post with the program code and data.

Comment: I'd need to ask for access to your google drive. I won't do that, and I hope nobody else would (that'd be a classic spam trap method). Please put your code somewhere it's easy to access, preferably the important part in the question itself, and the whole thing on e.g. gitlab.com, or github.com

Comment: @MarcusMüller done, I will remember for the future :)

Comment: @user46845 thank you :)

Comment: Where exactly in that implementation does the `RuntimeWarning` occur? I don't see any place where that might happen.

Comment: @MarcusMüller pleas, see image.

Comment: That doesn't help. Find the line which introduces that error. You can run Python outside of Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Editor Conda Spyder: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars `y[n] = y[n] + a[i]*y[n-i]  `

Comment: so, great, now you actually do know the line where that happens!

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume that it is `a` that is equal to `array([ 1.        , -3.9671626 ,  5.90202586, -3.90255878,  0.96769554])`.

Second, that array when you go through all the z-domain stuff, you find that you are representing the difference equation
$$\sum_{k=0}^N a_k y_{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^N b_k x_{n-k}$$

If you solve that for $y_n$ you get

$$y_n = -\sum_{k=1}^N a_k y_{n-k} + \sum_{k=0}^N b_k x_{n-k}$$

**Note the minus sign** in front of the summation of the prior terms of $y$ -- your code is missing that.  So you've turned your denominator polynomial from $a(z) = 1 - 3.967z^{-1} + 5.902z^{-2} \cdots$ into $a(z) = 1 + 3.967z^{-1} - 5.902z^{-2} \cdots$.  *That* polynomial is almost certainly unstable, and you're overflowing even what double-precision floating point can represent.

**Note 1:**

In general, it's better to break filters down into the smallest sections you can and cascade them.  This is because (a) it is the filter poles and zeros that are important to filter behavior, but polynomial roots get absurdly sensitive to polynomial coefficient variation as the order goes up, and (b) the filter's susceptibility to rounding in the data -- even with perfect coefficients -- goes up pretty much the same as a polynomial's sensitivity to coefficient variation.

So -- small polynomials are good, which means low-order filters are good.

Your filter design function *should* be able to cough up a form where it gives you poles & zeros instead of polynomials; you can then break those into 2nd-order functions.

**Note 2:**

You're using Scipy, which -- if I'm not mistaken -- has a built-in filtering function, and it should be compatible with the poles & zeros form of the filter design output.  If you're rolling your own filter code to learn it -- good for you, keep it up, we need people to know what's going on under the hood.  If you just need to filter some @#$% data and get on with life, use the built-in Scipy function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My basic mistake is the implementation. If n = 0 and then i do y[n-i] the index is -1, -2 etc...

Comment: Some code changes and now it's ok. @TimWescott Thank you. !!!